# La acción 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/SCT' no es válida o no se reconoce

Tags: c#, wcf, .asmx

Tengo un servicio web asmx integrado con WSE3.0 y estoy intentando migrarlo a un servicio web en WCF, para la migración estoy usando este documento:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/migrating-wse-3-0-web-services-to-wcf

Esta es la configuración original del archivo de WSE:

```
<policies xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wse/2005/06/policy">
<extensions>
    <extension name="mutualCertificate11Security" type="Microsoft.Web.Services3.Design.MutualCertificate11Assertion, Microsoft.Web.Services3, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <extension name="x509" type="Microsoft.Web.Services3.Design.X509TokenProvider, Microsoft.Web.Services3, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <extension name="requireActionHeader" type="Microsoft.Web.Services3.Design.RequireActionHeaderAssertion, Microsoft.Web.Services3, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
</extensions>
<policy name="x509">
    <mutualCertificate11Security establishSecurityContext="true" renewExpiredSecurityContext="true" requireSignatureConfirmation="true" messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncrypt" requireDerivedKeys="false" ttlInSeconds="300">
        <serviceToken>
             <x509 storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My" findValue="WCfServer" findType="FindBySubjectName" />
        </serviceToken>
        <protection>
            <request signatureOptions="IncludeAddressing, IncludeTimestamp, IncludeSoapBody" encryptBody="true" />
            <response signatureOptions="IncludeAddressing, IncludeTimestamp, IncludeSoapBody" encryptBody="true" />
            <fault signatureOptions="IncludeAddressing, IncludeTimestamp, IncludeSoapBody" encryptBody="false" />
        </protection>
    </mutualCertificate11Security>
    <requireActionHeader />
</policy>
```

Y esta es la configuración que estoy haciendo al servicio WCF:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior"  name="ServiceDemo">
    <endpoint address=""
        binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceDemoConf" 
        contract="IServiceDemo" >        
    </endpoint>
  <host>
    <baseAddresses>
      <add baseAddress="http://localhost:47037/"/>
    </baseAddresses>
  </host>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="ServiceDemoConf">          
    <security authenticationMode="MutualCertificate" 
              canRenewSecurityContextToken="true"
                 requireSignatureConfirmation="true" 
                 messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncrypt"  
                 messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11"
                 requireDerivedKeys="false" >
      </security>
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion ="Soap11WSAddressingAugust2004" >
      </textMessageEncoding>
      <httpTransport />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior" >
      <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="WCfServer"
                            storeLocation="CurrentUser"
                            storeName="My"
                            x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

Al consumir el servicio,arroja una excepción cuyo detalle es el siguiente:

> La acción 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/SCT' no es
>   válida o no se reconoce.

Me pueden indicar si falta algo a la configuración del servicio WCF para poder consumir el servicio sin errores.

Answer (score 1):

Ya pude encontrar la causa del error y era en la configuración de custombinding en el lado del servicio WCF, esta es la configuración que se debe hacer:

```
 <binding name="ServiceDemoConf">       
 <security authenticationMode="SecureConversation"
                   requireSignatureConfirmation="false"
                   canRenewSecurityContextToken="true"
                   messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncrypt"
                   messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11"
                   requireDerivedKeys="false" >
      <secureConversationBootstrap 
           authenticationMode="MutualCertificate"
           requireSignatureConfirmation="true"
                   canRenewSecurityContextToken="true"
                   messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncrypt"
                   messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11" 
                   requireDerivedKeys="false">
      </secureConversationBootstrap>
    </security>
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion ="Soap11WSAddressingAugust2004"  >
      </textMessageEncoding>
      <httpTransport />
    </binding>
```